# How to translate @Constraint messages in Symfony 2.8?

Tags: symfony, constraints, translation

The Cookbook show how [to translate assert messages](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages), but how to do the same on @Constraint annotations on a class level? Example which is not working :

```
 use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints as Constraint;

 /**
 * @Constraint\UniqueEntity(
 *     fields={"mobileDomainName"},
 *     errorPath="mobileDomainName",
 *     message="site.validation.mobileName.alreadyUsed"
 * )
 */
 class Site {
```

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT :** translator is activated, all others classical calls worked (including Assert annotations).

Comment: is it possible that the translator is not enabled? have a look in app/config/config.yml . Also you'll need to clear the cache each time you update translations

Comment: No, AFAIK translator enabled, it's working on other classical calls : framework: translator:      { fallback: "%locale%" }

Comment: Have you tried [Translating Constraint Messages](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages) from the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to A.L comment, I read again [the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/book/translation.html#translating-constraint-messages) (that I already tried to follow). But I misread the translation file name (i.e. **validators.language.filetype**), whereas I orignally dropped my translations in my custom validation file.

With all constraints validation in good file, all is working.

Thanks for your answers and pointing.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have to enable translator in the config

```
translator: { 
    fallbacks: ['%locale%'] 
}
```

like Adam Elsodaney said.